# Storing keypoints and descriptors (Python/OpenCV)

Tags: python, csv, opencv, numpy

I'm new to OpenCV and Python. I'd trying to store the `keypoints` and `descriptors` of thousands of images into in a CSV. I would love it if I could just store every row like: [`kps`, `descs`, `image_name`, `metadata`].

That way I could simply go through each `row` with a `for` loop, and load the `kps` and `descs` arrays into variables to run in my search function.

Originally I tried writing it directly to a CSV file like so:

```
data = [[kps, descs, "some string", "some metadata")]]
writer.writerows(data)
```

But I'm not sure it was preserving the numpy arrays properly. Or, am I doing this incorrectly? Should the tuple of `(kps, descs)` be wrapped and saved together somehow?

Any help appreciated. Thanks